# Fuerte: segfault for rviz and gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu Oneiric. I found that segmentation fault occurs when I start gazebo and rviz.

Error messages for gazebo are:

```
Dbg pluginPaths and GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH doesn't exist.Set GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH to Ogre's installation path. ...or are you loading via SystemPlugins?
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.0
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Dbg pluginPaths and GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH doesn't exist.Set GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH to Ogre's installation path. ...or are you loading via SystemPlugins?
Msg Waiting for master.[ INFO] [1335783536.626143462]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Error [Transport.cc:96] Unable to get topic namespaces in [50] tries.
Error [Node.cc:68] No namespace found
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  2125 Segmentation fault   `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -p `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 2122, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/wei/.ros/log/75664e3e-92b3-11e1-8a65-0022fb5dd250/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/wei/.ros/log/75664e3e-92b3-11e1-8a65-0022fb5dd250/gazebo_gui-3*.log
^C[empty_world_server-2] killing on exit
[empty_world_server-2] escalating to SIGTERM
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Error messages for rviz are:

```
[ INFO] [1335784163.509573136]: rviz revision number 1.8.11
[ INFO] [1335784163.509793346]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1335784173.348856540]: Loading general config from [/home/wei/.rviz/config]
Segmentation fault
```

What would be the possible reason for these errors?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32970/fuerte:-segfault-for-rviz-and-gazebo/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-04-30

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please read the page http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting#Segfault_during_startup

and try each mode of these: copy PBuffer FBO, maybe one of them will work!

---

Originally posted by [Barton.Qi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3040/barton.qi/) with karma: 41 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1